# Merge 2 arrays based on index without overwriting in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative array which I want to merge based on the index / key of an array, i don't want it to overwrite any of the array values from the index.

```
Array 1:
Array
(
    [66529] => Array
        (
            [Download] => ON
        )
    [66587] => Array
        (
           [Download] => ON
        )
)

Array 2:
Array
(
    [66587] => Array
        (
            [PPT] => ON
        )
    [66529] => Array
        (
            [PPT] => OFF
        )
)
```

Merged Array should be:

```
Array
(
    [66529] => Array
        (
            [Download] => ON
            [PPT] => OFF
        )
    [66587] => Array
        (
           [Download] => ON
            [PPT] => ON
        )
)
```

I know this can be done using the loops, but I am looking for in-built php functions to do this.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#example-5522

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051782/php-array-merge-recursive-preserving-numeric-keys)

Comment: You cant have duplicate keys in php arrays, or simply said: it will always overwrite unless you change the key.

Comment: @Peter, not with `array_merge_recursive`

Comment: @DevDonkey I stand corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got the expected result. Below is the solution that works for me

$result = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);